# Codesys CAA_File and SysFile library difference

Tags: codesys

What is the difference between Codesys CAA_File lib and SysFile lib?  When to use CAA_File instead of SysFile?

Answer (score 5):

**SysFile** 
Makes a direct call to the CODESYS Runtime component. This API is used by the CODESYS Runtime to download program / open programs ETC.
Its very optimized in the sense that every function does a very well define task.
All the functions here a very low level.

**CAA_File**, 
Uses a standardized API (defined by the CAA Workgroup), focused on the IEC Programmer needs. 
It takes a more high level approach, giving you extra functionality that will not find in SysFile (but you can implement it yourself).

At the end, CAA_File ends up calling SysFile.

Depending on your target, you might not be able to use SysFile. Linux / Windows devices usually come with all the components.

I would use SysFile only if I wanted to create my own library or if I wanted to have a very efficient process, or if I didn't require any special protection / features.

If I wanted to keep things simple I would use CAA_File.

Source: I have integrated CODESYS Runtime into custom embedded platforms.